# Can't connect to SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So i created a database on Microsoft SQL server 2014 called `WaitListData` and created a table called Table, i added 5 columns. I want my C# program to insert data into these columns when a button is pressed.

My problem is (and i have researched this problem for hours) that no matter what i do, i always get the same error when i click my button, which is:`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` in `System.Data.dll`

Obviously my application is going to be a lot more than just a button but i cannot seem to just get this basic function to work properly and its very frustrating. I can connect to database using Visual Studio's Server explorer and do whatever i want from there but that isn't what i need.

So any help on this would be very much appreciated, if anyone needs additional information then i will happily try to provide it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=PH-IT-CC1@SQLEXPRESS;Database=WaitListData;Trusted_Connection=True");
        myConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Nationality, Time_Of_Play) " + "VALUES ('" + txtFirstname1.Text + "' , '" + txtLastname1.Text + "' , '" + txtEmail1.Text + "' , '" + txtNationality1.Text + "' , '" + txtTimeOfPlay1.Text + "')", myConnection);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would help if we knew what the exception message was

Comment: Can you connect to the database using SQL SMS on the same machine? How are you authenticating the user?

Comment: Here is the exception message:   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Yes, on SQL SMS, i can connect using PH-IT-CC1\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: try it with 2 backslashes : PH-IT-CC1\\SQLEXPRESS or pc-ip\\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: change `PH-IT-CC1@SQLEXPRESS` to `PH-IT-CC1\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS`. Also check for TCP ports settings to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Might found silly, but this happened with me once. 
1. Close the IIS express locally and then run the app again.
2. If the DB is installed locally, change the server name to (local) or try IP address instead of hostname.